# NS_STRING_ENUM doesn't produce enum

Tags: swift3, xcode8

Ever since Xcode 8 as released we have been given NS_STRING_ENUM and NS_EXTENSIBLE_STRING_ENUM.  As describing in Apple's documentation, Objective-c global strings attributed with NS_EXTENSIBLE_STRING_ENUM are imported to Swift structs while NS_STRING_ENUM imports them as enum string.  Yet in practice both attributes become stucts.

Is there a subtly that I am missing or is this just a bug.

```
// traffic.h
typedef NSString * TrafficLightColor NS_STRING_ENUM;

static TrafficLightColor const TrafficLightColorRed = @"Red";
static TrafficLightColor const TrafficLightColorYellow = @"Yellow";
static TrafficLightColor const TrafficLightColorGreen = @"Green";
```

The documentation says it will become imported to swift as:

```
enum TrafficLightColor: String {
    case red
    case yellow
    case green
}
```

However this isn't the case.  Instead it is ported to swift as a struct:

```
struct TrafficLightColor : RawRepresentable, _SwiftNewtypeWrapper, Equatable, Hashable, Comparable, _ObjectiveCBridgeable {
    static let red: TrafficLightColor
    static let yellow: TrafficLightColor
    static let green: TrafficLightColor
}
```

So in short NS_EXTENSIBLE_STRING_ENUM works as described by Apple documentation.  Yet, NS_STRING_ENUM does not.  Is there a something that I need to change to make NS_STRING_ENUM produce an enum string in swift?

Comment: Your observation is good. But since the textbook example itself does not work, what kind of answer would satisfy you except that the textbook example is obviously wrong? And that is something that, equally obviously, you already know. As to whether it's a bug, that's also obviously impossible to say: Is Swift importing this thing incorrectly, or was the author of the document mistaken?

Comment: (By the way, I believe that this did work as advertised at one time.)

Comment: I filed a bug report. 29128685 . I suppose if enough people complain about it Apple will fix it.  As for the document writer being mistaken, I suppose 3 sources being wrong means the writer was mistaken 3 times (or more).  The 3 sources are: 1) Swift Evolution (SE-0033) 2) Xcode Quick Help 3)  Apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html

Comment: That's why I mentioned that this seems to have worked at some point. I'm using Xcode 8.1 and you probably are too, but you might try whipping out an older version just to see. Xcode 8, or even a beta if you have one lying around.

Comment: By the way, your bug report number makes it sound like you filed at `bugreport.apple.com`. I recommend using `bugs.swift.org` instead.

Comment: Well, if it did work then it must have been in a pre-Xcode 8 beta 4

Comment: Yes, I did file it to bug report.apple.com I'll try the other one you recommended

Comment: It must have been working on September 23, because otherwise this bug report would make no sense: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2742